# Python - Excel keeps creating new sheet (Adding 1 to the end of the sheet name) each time I go through a loop reading .txt files

Tags: python, pandas, excel

What I want: I want the code to look at the folder that the files are in, name the sheet in excel the same as the folder, then read each .txt file (Each .txt file contains one column of data) and insert it into an excel file. [image: Similar to this layout, all the files in a folder, data on one sheet named (Folder name), each file on its own column]

What it is doing: It is taking each file and adding it into a sheet, along with putting data into the next column over, BUT it is creating a new sheet each time (So for 16 files, its creating 16 sheets named FOLDER_A, FOLDER_A1, etc.).

Example: Create xlsx file (final_results). For Folder A (16 files), read all txt files, put each column of data into final_results sheet A, expecting 16 columns of data. For Folder B (15 files), read all txt files, put each column of data into final_results sheet B, expecting 15 columns of data.

Here is a snip of my code: I am looking at a determined path, going into that path, looking at all of the folders in that path and counting how many there is. Then I am looking at how many files is in each folder.

```
import sys   
import os
from os import walk
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl, pprint
from statistics import mean,stdev
import time
import json
import re
import openpyxl
#from UliPlot.XLSX import auto_adjust_xlsx_column_width



## PLEASE CREATE RESULTS EXCEL FILES BEFORE RUNNING TEST (Results.xlsx) WITHOUT THE CREATION, PROGRAM WILL NOT RUN.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    command = ''
    start= time.time()

    #Target path
    dir_path = os.getcwd()+"/output"
    print(dir_path)

    #res2 prints out all files under all the output folder that contain x100
    #res2 = []
    
##Os.walk - Finds directories starting with Chassis and Accel - This could be customized with user input - Adds the output or folders to a list
    directories =[]
    print("Trying os.walk")
    def list_files_recursive(dir_path):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
            #for file in files:
                #if file.startswith("x100"):
                    #print(os.path.join(root, file))
                    #res2.append(file)
            for dir in dirs:
                if dir.startswith(('Chassis','Accel')):
                    #print(os.path.join(root, dirs))
                    directories.append(dir)
        #print (res2)
        #print(directories)
    list_files_recursive('.')
    

##Create Excel sheet - Can change this later for user input
    example = "example.xlsx"
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2.to_excel(example, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Delete_me')
    # df1 = pd.DataFrame(directories)
    
##Calculate number of directories
    lst = os.listdir(dir_path) # your directory path
    numberofdirs = int(len(lst))
    print("Number of directories: ",numberofdirs)

##Calculate number of files in each folder
   #d is the int that counts the loop
    d=-1

    #Create dictionary for folders names and number of files in each folder
    numberof_files={} 
    while True:
        d+=1
        if (d <numberofdirs):
            #1st folder
            #print(d) , if need to find issues with loop later
            lst = os.listdir(dir_path+"/"+directories[d]) # your directory path
            numberof_files[directories[d]] = int(len(lst))
            
            #Below print command, prints out file path of each folder in targeted directory
            #print (glob.glob(dir_path+"/"+directories[d]))

            #Used for manually finding file numbers in folder
            """#2nd folder (Change res3 # and numberof_files#)
            lst = os.listdir(dir_path+"/"+directories[2]) # your directory path
            numberof_files2 = int(len(lst))
            print ("Number of files in directory: " , numberof_files2)
            print (glob.glob(dir_path+"/"+directories[2]))"""
            continue
         
        else:
            print ("Number of files in directory: " , numberof_files)
            print("moving on.. Starting data transfer to excel sheet")
            break
            

##Start of while loop to put data into excel sheet
    i=0
    folder=0
    print("Starting on folder: ", directories[folder])

#Add excel sheet for first folder and check length of characters(Excel doesnt allow sheet names over 31 characters) 
    
    dict_to_string = str(directories[folder])
    print (dict_to_string)

    if len(dict_to_string) >= 30:
            print ("Folder Name too long for Excel Sheet Name (Over 31 Characters)!!")
            dict_to_string2 = input('Please type in new Excel Sheet Name: ')

    else:    

        dict_to_string2=dict_to_string

##Start of while loop that looks at all files and folders and adds them to excel sheet
    while True: 
        #i is file counter               
        i+=1
        #print (numberof_files[directories[folder]])

        #Loop for 1st folder
        if ((i <= numberof_files[directories[folder]]) and (folder <numberofdirs)):

            #Path of all of the folders
            dir_path2= dir_path+"/"+directories[folder]

            # list to store files, do this for each folder
            file_list = []
            # Iterate directory
            #print(os.listdir(dir_path2))
            for file in os.listdir(dir_path2):
                # check only text files
                if file.endswith('.txt'):
                    file_list.append(file)

            print ("Targeting File: "+dir_path2+"/"+file_list[i-1])

            
            #Read data from each file that is iterated
            df2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir_path2+"/"+file_list[i-1]))

            #Send read data to excel sheet
            #df2.to_excel(file_list[i-1]+'.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
        
            with pd.ExcelWriter(example,engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='error') as excel_writer:
                 df2.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name=dict_to_string2, index=False,startcol=i-1)
                 print(i-1)
                 excel_writer.save()
                 excel_writer.close()
                 
                 
            #df2.to_excel(example,directories[folder])


                       
    
            ##Goes to this IF loop once all files are added to excel file, this resets file count and goes to next folder
            if i>=numberof_files[directories[folder]] :
                i=0
                folder +=1

                #Combine all worksheets (Code above creates seperate sheet in excel for each file) *Not working*
                """df_merge = pd.read_excel(example,sheet_name=None).values()
                df_merge = [dfx.transpose().reset_index().transpose() for dfx in df_merge]

                df_final = pd.concat(df_merge, axis= 1, ignore_index=True,sort=True)
                df_final.to_excel("Final_thermal.xlsx", index=False, header=False)"""

                #Check character length of sheet name, have user input sheet name if over 30 characters
                print()
                print("Switching to folder: ",directories[folder])
                print()

                #Make folder name into string
                dict_to_string = str(directories[folder])
                print (dict_to_string)
                
                #If folder name is over 30 characters, tell user to change it
                if len(dict_to_string)> 30:
                    print ("Folder Name too long for Excel Sheet Name (Over 31 Characters)!!")
                    dict_to_string2 = input('Please type in new Excel Sheet Name: ')
                    print()

                elif len(dict_to_string)< 30:
                    dict_to_string2=dict_to_string

            continue
        else :
             print("Done")
             break
```

Pictures of what its doing:
[FolderA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIEUn.png)
[FolderA1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUbMf.png)

I want these columns combined into one sheet

Thanks for the help!

I have tried changing pandas engines, changing modes, I cant get anything to work the way I want it to.

Comment: So many undefined name/variables. The code you provide needs to be a mre (minimal reproducible example). i.e. enough to reproduce the error you are experiencing, Having to try and guess what your code is doing is made that much harder when there is no detail on what/how a variable value is determined. Its also OK to show what modules are being imported.

Comment: @moken Hi. Thank you for your quick reply. I just added all of the code. If you look at the two attachments (Folder a and a1) you can see what its producing. When the code is in the WHILE loop, it will go through # iterations (#=number of files in the folder) with each iteration opening the txt file in a folder, reading it, and placing the data from the txt file into a column in the excel results sheet under the sheet name ("Folder" or directiories[folder] variable).

Comment: continued.. 
so this should look at a folder, saving the folder name in a list, looking at files, also saving to a list, then going through each folder, copying folder name to the sheet name in excel and adding txt data to that sheet, for all txt files under that folder

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to combine the txt files into one big CSV, and then import the CSV?  Text is way easier to work with than XLSX files.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have thought about doing that, was just trying to work with the raw data and do less "conversions"

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code, bit difficult to follow but from that and your description/comments it seems the text files you want to insert into Excel are located a sub directory called 'output'. It then seems the requisite directories to look for in 'output' must start with the words 'Chassis' or 'Accel' based on the 'list_files_recursive' function. The code then gets the number of text files in each of these directories. Then reads each text file and inserts into the Excel file.
The folder naming seems different to in the description to the code but this should be trivial.

**Issues**
As I see it there are some problems that prevent the code from running as is;
Some of these are;

1. A loop gets a list of the text files in the directories that start with the words 'Chassis' or 'Accel' but uses the total number of directories in 'output' as an the index when looping later on. Therefore if there are more directories than those that start with 'Chassis' or 'Accel' an out of index error will result. If there are no directories in 'output' that don't start with 'Chassis' or 'Accel' then the 'list_files_recursive' function seems extraneous.
2. There seems to be be some unnecessary re-execution of code. For example the loop that writes the text files to Excel contains a loop gets the names all the text files in the current folder to add. After the write of the first text file to Excel the loop cycles, increases variable 'i' for the next column and then runs the same loop again to get all the text files in the folder, and does this for each text file. Should only get this list once.
3. The `to_excel` write to the Excel file has `if_sheet_exists='error'`, so for the next and subsequent text files to be written an error will occur as the sheet now exists.
   `if_sheet_exists=` should be set to `if_sheet_exists='overlay'`.
    'error' literally means return an error if the named sheet already exists in the workbook, whereas 'overlay' basically means incorporate the data into the sheet if it exists.
4. After a directory's text files are written to the Excel file there is a process to move to the next directory by increasing the index used (named 'folder') to select the directory name from the list 'directories' but there is no check on the maximum value the index can be allowing a request using an index beyond the maximum allowed resulting in an 'index out of range error'.

There are a few other small issues but otherwise apart from the above main issues the code does work.

**Code**
I've re-written the code as shown below which hopefully should be easier to understand. The code sample below produces the required workbook as required summarised in my first paragraph.
Any missed requirements should be easy to change or add in.

For testing I have a directory called 'output' with three directories called 'Accel', 'Chassis' and 'NotUsed'. 
'Accel' has two text files, 'Chassis' has four text files and 'NotUsed' has one text file. 
We expect only text files from the two directories 'Accel' & 'Chassis' are added to the workbook while the directory 'NotUsed' is ignored.

Test directory structure

```
C:\Temp\Test
├── example.xlsx   <--- Excel file created on script run
├── output
│   ├── Accel
│   │   ├── 1.txt
│   │   ├── 2.txt
│   │   └── file1.doc
│   ├── Chassis
│   │   ├── 3.txt
│   │   ├── 4.txt
│   │   ├── 5.txt
│   │   └── 6.txt
│   └── NotUsed
│       └── 7.txt
└── pandas1i.py   < -- Python script
```

Proposed update to the code that should be easier to understand

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

def list_files_recursive(dir_path):
    dir_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for dir in dirs:
            if dir.startswith(('Chassis', 'Accel')):
                dir_list.append(dir)

    return dir_list


example = "example.xlsx"
dir_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "output")
print(dir_path)

print("Trying os.walk")
directories = list_files_recursive('.')

### Calculate number of directories
num_dirs = len(directories)
print(f"Number of directories: {num_dirs}")

### Calculate number of files in each folder
numberof_files = {}
for x in range(num_dirs):
    numberof_files[directories[x]] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(dir_path, directories[x])))

print("Number of files in directory: ", numberof_files)
print("moving on.. Starting data transfer to excel sheet\n")

### Loop the required directories to extract and add to the Excel workbook
for folder in directories:
    sheet_name = folder

    if len(sheet_name) > 30:
        print("Folder Name too long for Excel Sheet Name (Over 31 Characters)!!")
        sheet_name = input('Please type in new Excel Sheet Name: ')
        print()


    print(f"Inserting files from folder: {folder}")

    ### Loop the .txt files in {folder} and insert into the Excel sheet with same name
    ### enumerate is used as the Column count, it increments for each text file
    ### Loop only selects files with '.txt' extension
    for col, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, folder, '*.txt'))):
        print(filename)
        mode = 'a'  # default will to be append dataframe
        sheet_exists = 'overlay'  # Add the dataframe into the existing sheet

        ### If the Excel workbook doesn't exist (first loop) then create it. Otherwise append to existing
        if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), example)):
            mode = 'w'
            sheet_exists = None  # this param is only valid for append mode so set to None for write mode

        ### Create dataframe from the text file
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)

        ### Write the dataframe to the Excel workbook
        with pd.ExcelWriter(example, engine='openpyxl', mode=mode, if_sheet_exists=sheet_exists) as excel_writer:
            df.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, startcol=col)

    print('----------------------------------------------------')
```

The output

```
Trying os.walk
Number of directories: 2
Number of files in directory:  {'Accel': 2, 'Chassis': 4}
moving on.. Starting data transfer to excel sheet

Inserting files from folder: Accel
C:\Temp\Test\output\Accel\1.txt
C:\Temp\Test\output\Accel\2.txt
----------------------------------------------------
Inserting files from folder: Chassis
C:\Temp\Test\output\Chassis\3.txt
C:\Temp\Test\output\Chassis\4.txt
C:\Temp\Test\output\Chassis\5.txt
C:\Temp\Test\output\Chassis\6.txt
----------------------------------------------------
```

Example.xlsx workbook, two Sheets with each text file in next column.
[image: Resultant workbook]

**Other Notes**
Your code has the comment;
*## PLEASE CREATE RESULTS EXCEL FILES BEFORE RUNNING TEST (Results.xlsx) WITHOUT THE CREATION, PROGRAM WILL NOT RUN.*
The file 'Results.xlsx' doesn't exist or is referred to in your code, however if this file is required the code can check if it exists and create it if not either at the start or when it's required.

Comment: Hi Moken. Thank you so much for helping out here. I tried the code but am still getting each txt file print in its own sheet. 

My number of files in directory is also printing the txt files, not number of txt files..

Number of files in directory:  {'Chassis': ['x100.... etc all files in that folder']

Comment: I did miss that my IDE refactoring the word 'Chassis' to a test name and for testing was showing the files in the directory rather than counting the number. These are now corrected in the code. As stated in the answer, your code works for me after basically changing the ExcelWriter to overlay. My update is based on your description and how your code executes. I don't follow how it can be reading the text files but putting on separate sheets if the directory holding the text files has two or more files. Show the full output printed during the execution.

Comment: I have included a print out of the directory structure used for testing in the answer. If what you have is different please advise. The incorrect 'startswith' name would have just meant that the 'Chassis' directory would not have been picked up and the printing of the files names rather than count should have no impact on the inserting of files to the Excel workbook. You should have still had the 'example.xlsx' file produced and the files from the 'Accel' directory added to the one sheet called 'Accel'

Comment: I figured out what my issue was. My pandas module was out of date, therefore not allowing me to use the overlay function. My above code works and your code now works for me.

Comment: OK, good. So I suggest you look at the Issues as noted and compare with my example for looking at reducing the code and avoiding unnecessary duplication/execution. It makes it easier to understand what the code is doing and helps for debugging. It might also run faster.